# How to configure and use DailyRollingFileAppender for logging in Android

Tags: java, android, log4j

I'm using `android-logging-log4j-1.0.2.jar` and `log4j-1.2.16.jar` for doing logging in Android. My requirement is creating new log files dependent over date on daily basis. I figured out that this thing can be achieved using `DailyRollingFileAppender`but I'm unable to configure the it for logging purpose.

What are the standard methods for logging in Android, and how to properly configure `android-logging-log4j-1.0.2.jar` and `log4j-1.2.16.jar` libraries for my use-case.